# Proguard obfuscation causing cryptic error

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I am building a release apk which is obfuscated with Proguard. I have added the first two rules to help me decode any errors that the logcat may spit out.

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class * 
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
-dontwarn rx.internal.**

#Butterknife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
@butterknife.* <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
@butterknife.* <methods>;
}


#EventBus
-keepclassmembers class ** {
 public void onEvent*(**);
}

#JodaTime 

-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

The error on app crash is as follows:

```
AndroidRuntime:Error at com.example.app.e.b.a(SourceFile:65)
AndroidRuntime:Error at com.example.app.e.b.doInBackground(SourceFile:21)
```

The first two rules helped by showing me the the actual line numbers but I am having trouble figuring out what 'e.b.a' and 'e.b' are hinting at. Any help will be much appreciated.

## EDIT:

After using the ReTrace tool I received the following:

```
07-30 13:38:44.886 E/AndroidRuntime(5563): Process: com.example.app, PID: 5563
07-30 13:38:44.886 E/AndroidRuntime(5563):  at com.example.app.e.c$a.a(SourceFile:266)
07-30 13:38:44.886 E/AndroidRuntime(5563):  at com.example.app.e.c$a.doInBackground(SourceFile:250)
07-30 13:38:44.886 E/ActivityManager(1173): App crashed! Process: com.example.app
```

Comment: There should be a mapping.txt file somewhere in your project directory. This file is generated by ProGuard and contains information about the renaming of methods, fields, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the documentation on proguard http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html you will see that you can use proguard included in the sdk tools to deobfuscate stack traces.

`retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt`

As you can see there, if you use the mapping.txt file generated when you built your APK (or JAR in vanilla Java) you can unobfuscate stack traces.

If you prefer to use a GUI you can also look inside your Android SDK folder `<path>/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.{bat|sh}`. The GUI allows you to select your mapping file and then copy/paste stack traces into the window to deobfuscate.

Comment: I have followed your steps and the stack trace was still not completely de-obfuscated. I have included it my edit above. Thank you.

Comment: You need to trim off the logcat garbage. Unfortunately proguard isn't very smart when it comes to retracing it seems. Each line should start with 'at' except for the first line and often the last line.

Comment: Aha! That did the trick! Once again, thank you so much for your help.